# How to remove floats so items don't wrap with CSS only in this Codepen

Tags: jquery, html, css

**http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/talGc/**

So having an interesting problem here.

I've got a left and right div

The left div has 3 elements in it:

1) Person 1
2) WANTS TO MEET sign
3) Person 2

The right div just a paragraph, both divs are close to 50% width each.

Now if you shrink the browser window, the items inside of the left div will start to wrap. If I know exactly how wide the contents inside of the left div will always be this wouldn't be a problem, I could just solve it with media queries.

So here is my problem, the elements inside the left div will always change so I can't find the perfect media query to break on and remove the floats.

I believe I can fix this problem in jQuery by calculating the width of all the elements inside the left div, and check to see if it matches the width of their container on window resize then remove the floats. However that seems like doing too much and using too much to solve this problem.

Is there a CSS solution to this?

All my code is in the CodePen link above, here is the mediaQuery I'm using to remove the floats at 1205px. But again I will never know the correct size to break everytime since the widths will change:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1205px) {
  .the_requestor, .the_requested, .wants_to_meet {
      float: none;
  }

  .the_requestor {
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  }

  .request_details_left {
        margin-top: 0;
        border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  }

  .request_details_right {
      width: 40%;
      border: 0;
  }
}
```

**Screenshots:**
Large Desktop - correct look
[image]

Resizing the window - problematic look (This is what I want to avoid)
[image]

Resized small Desktop - correct look
[image]

Comment: Just a suggestion - but maybe try `clear:both;`?  Not sure.

Comment: I'm using `overflow: auto` to clear my floats. That's not the problem here. When you resize, I want to make sure that users never see the wrapping the 2nd screenshot

Comment: `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle` should do the trick

Comment: I actually just thought up a hack fix for this. I could set an exact width on all 3 elements in the left div. Then I can figure out when to break it... I starting to think that could be the only way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/talGc/

Found a way :) the elements inside the left div I had to give them a specific set width. Then removed the floats on them.

```
@media all and (max-width: 1205px) {
    .the_requestor, .the_requested, .wants_to_meet {
        float: none;
        background: orange;
    }

    .the_requestor {
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    }

    .request_details_left {
        margin-top: 0;
        border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    }

    .request_details_right {
        width: 40%;
        border: 0;
    }

    .the_requestor,
    .the_requested,
        .wants_to_meet {
        float: none;  
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
.request_details_left,
.the_requestor,
.wants_to_meet,
.the_requested,
.request_details_right {
      float: left;
}
```

To

```
.request_details_left,
.request_details_right {
      float: left;
}


.the_requestor,
.wants_to_meet,
.the_requested {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but looks like I'm still having the problem here :( http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/IKqwl/

Answer (score 0):

maybe scaling is an option? See this **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GeLHz)**

I added a slider to mimic resizing the window.
I modified certain css elements to be sized in em's and set a main font-size in the body to 16px.  The slider is hooked into a bit of jquery that manipulates the font-size which in turn scales everything measured in em units.

Not sure if scaling is an option, but maybe you can figure out a way to tie that into your issue